# How can I implement both horizontal and vertical gradients on an html element

Tags: css, gradient

can someone point me how to implement gradient to **only** the top, bottom and right sides of an html div element using any of the mozilla gradient properties in css ?
if i do a vertical gradient using -moz-linear-gradient property, i'm missing out on the gradient to be applied on the right side of the div element.

Comment: what you want two gradient in a single div ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure this is what you want but you can nest a div element in the target div element, set a horizontal gradient in one and set a vertical gradient in the other. Then, change the opacity of the nested div element to 50%.

EDIT: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/ux9f2/) is a little rough around the edges but this works in Firefox. Note that you cannot change the opacity of child elements to a value higher than the the parent opacity. Child opacities are relative, not absolute.

Comment: +1: I don't care if it's what the OP wanted, it's a nice effect :)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible thanks to CSS3. Just put both vertical and horizontal gradient together on the same line, separated by a comma.

For example, to create this nice background
[image: the nice background démo]
I'm using this code :

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #80d0b9 0%,#80d0b9 30px,#e7f3f3 30px,#e7f3f3 100%) no-repeat top left,
            linear-gradient(to right,  #c2ebec 0%,#c2ebec 30px,#e7f3f3 30px,#e7f3f3 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
background-size: 30px 100%;
```

[Here is a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3rza1wqs/)